# How to handle errors on broken table links

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have recently updated my linked tables to use `UNC` links. However when I test the front end using a machine which does not have the mapped drives,
my error handling procedure fails in line `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ItemName FROM tblDonatedItems")` with error number `3044`
Is there a way of trapping the error so that the procedure can keep running? Please see below:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error Resume Next
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ItemName FROM tblDonatedItems")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " Please link to backend file!", , "Locate backend file"
Call AttachDataFile
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSplash"
End Sub
```

I have also tried this without success:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ItemName FROM tblDonatedItems")
ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " Please link to backend file!", , "Locate backend file"
Call AttachDataFile

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSplash"
    Else: MsgBox ("Error! Please email: info@abc.com Quoting Error Number: " & " Err.Number"), vbCritical
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSplash"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Include the full error message in your question. Mapped drives should be irrelevant with UNC pathing.

Comment: Put a break on the set rs = and then single step to find out to which line control passes.

Comment: @June7 it was a normal data file not found error when a link to the tables is broken. I did a compact and repair and then the code worked. I haven't come across this kind of behaviour before! I got a bit worried why the `OnError Resume Next` line was being ignore. Is this a common issue?

Comment: C&R can sometimes fix a corruption issue. Again, lack of drive mapping should not be an issue when using UNC pathing. I avoid the `On Error Resume Next` structure whenever possible, only ever used it once in a deployed db. And that's because it was in found code and didn't bother trying to figure how not to use.